# Parsing Date from database in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

This can be a small problem but i am getting confused with how to understand the date format stored in database.

in my Mysql database i have date stored as  `2014-12-02T01:15:00Z`

Now that looks to me a `01:15:00`

But on my Javascript it is coming as `12:15pm`

```
m = moment('2014-12-02T01:15:00Z')
m.format('YYYY-mm-DD hh:mm a')
"2014-15-02 12:15 pm"
```

I just want to know that how does that `01:15` becomes `12:15pm` may be i am missing something basic bit i could not find it

Comment: Have you tried outputting the `utc` version of the moment.js object?

Comment: Timezone difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time that you get back is based on your computer I believe. 
It does a conversion.

For instance:

```
var t = '2014-12-02T01:15:00Z';
console.log(new Date(t));
```

Then I would get:

```
Mon Dec 01 2014 17:15:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

What's being stored in MySQL is based on GMT.